# Custom counting method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

For learning purposes I've created a JS-File.
I implemented a Method inside the JS-Object to get a BookStorage counter.
The thing is everytime I add Books the Browser gives me back the default value for the Object. Anyone have an Idea?

Here is some snippets of my Code:

Book-Class:

```
class Book{
constructor(
    name,
    quantity
){
    this.name = name,
    this.quantity = quantity
}
showStorage(param) {
    if(param != null){
        return this.quantity + param;
        this.quantity += param;
    }
        else {return this.quantity;}
    }
}
```

Main-Script:

```
    import Book from "./Book.js"

const lordOfRings = new Book(
  "Lord of the Rings",
  10
)

console.log("The Book:", lordOfRings.name);
console.log("The number in Storage:", lordOfRings.showStorage());
console.log("Adding 10 Books to storage:", lordOfRings.showStorage(10));
console.log("Adding 10 Books to storage:", lordOfRings.showStorage());
console.log("New Storage amount of Books:", lordOfRings.showStorage(10));
```

My expected output was:

```
"Lord of the Rings"
10
20
20
30
```

Instead of that I get:

```
"Lord of the Rings"
10 
20 
10 
20
```

Comment: If you don't pass any argument, `param` is `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: In your `showStorage` method, you `return` before changing the value of `this.quantity`. Your `return` statement should be the very last thing you do in your method.

Comment: @DM, Thank you for the information too. For the conventions I will keep this in mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because in a function, the `return` should be the last line.

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller. ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return))

Since the function execution ends, it means the code after the `return` statement is never executed.

I recommend debugging your code using a [code execution visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=class%20Book%7B%0Aconstructor%28%0A%20%20%20%20name,%0A%20%20%20%20quantity%0A%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name,%0A%20%20%20%20this.quantity%20%3D%20quantity%0A%7D%0AshowStorage%28param%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%28param%20!%3D%20null%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.quantity%20%2B%20param%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.quantity%20%2B%3D%20param%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%7Breturn%20this.quantity%3B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20lordOfRings%20%3D%20new%20Book%28%0A%20%20%22Lord%20of%20the%20Rings%22,%0A%20%2010%0A%29%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%22The%20Book%3A%22,%20lordOfRings.name%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22The%20number%20in%20Storage%3A%22,%20lordOfRings.showStorage%28%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22Adding%2010%20Books%20to%20storage%3A%22,%20lordOfRings.showStorage%2810%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22Adding%2010%20Books%20to%20storage%3A%22,%20lordOfRings.showStorage%28%29%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28%22New%20Storage%20amount%20of%20Books%3A%22,%20lordOfRings.showStorage%2810%29%29%3B&cumulative=false&curInstr=14&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Here's part of your code. You tried to change the value of `this.quantity` after the `return` statement.

```js
showStorage(param) {
    if(param != null){
        return this.quantity + param; // This doesn't change the value of this.quantity. It just returns that value + 10 (in your example). The value of `this.quantity` is always the same.

        // This line does not run because it's after the return statement
        this.quantity += param;
    }
        else {return this.quantity;}
    }
}
```

Here's a minimal fix. You need to increment the value of `this.quantity`, **then** return it.

```js
showStorage(param) {
    if(param != null){
        this.quantity += param;
        return this.quantity;
    }
        else {return this.quantity;}
    }
}
```

Here's a refactor taking into account comments from [Ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773497/custom-counting-method-in-javascript#comment128541346_72773661) and [Cristian Traìna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72773497/custom-counting-method-in-javascript#comment128540999_72773497)

```js
showStorage(param) {
    if(param){ // an empty `param` is `undefined`, not `null` as the commenter said above.
        this.quantity += param;
    }
    return this.quantity;
}
```

Comment: Good point @Ivar! I was intending to only change the parts of the code that caused the unexpected behavior. I added an option to show your suggestion too.